# Homework help? logarithmic derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f_1, \ldots , f_n, g_1, \ldots, g_m$ be functions differentiable at the point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and assume moreover that $f_\ell(z_0) \neq 0$ for $\ell = 1, \ldots, n$ and $g_\jmath(z_0) \neq 0$ for $\jmath = 1, \ldots, m$. Show that

$\frac{\frac{f_1 \cdots f_n}{g_1 \cdots g_m}'(z_0)}{\frac{f_1 \cdots f_n}{g_1 \cdots g_m}(z_0)}$ = $\sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{f'_\ell (z_0)}{f_\ell (z_0)} - \sum_{\jmath=1}^m \frac{g'_\jmath (z_0)}{g_\jmath (z_0)}$

$\mathbb{C}$-differentiability at a given point $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$ imples that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at the point $(x_0, y_0)$.

source: Daniel Alpay's: A Complex Analysis Problem Book page 149 exercise 4.2.2.

so I'm not sure if its correct, but I used the quotient rule to solve this. My work is below. I feel that I went wrong somewhere. If someone can point it out I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

$\frac{\frac{f_1 \cdots f_n}{g_1 \cdots g_m}'(z_0)}{\frac{f_1 \cdots f_n}{g_1 \cdots g_m}(z_0)}$ = $\frac{\frac{f'_\ell (z_0) g_\jmath (z_0) - f_\ell (z_0) g'_\jmath (z_0)}{g_\jmath (z_0)^2}}{\frac{f_\ell (z_0)}{g_\jmath (z_0)}}$

= $\frac{f'_\ell (z_0)g_\jmath (z_0) - f_\ell (z_0)g'_\jmath (z_0)}{f_\ell (z_0)g_\jmath (z_0)}$ = $\frac{f'_\ell (z_0)g_\jmath (z_0)}{f_\ell (z_0)g_\jmath (z_0)}$ - $\frac{f_\ell (z_0)g'_\jmath (z_0)}{f_\ell (z_0)g_\jmath (z_0)}$

= $\sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{f'_\ell (z_0)}{f_\ell (z_0)} - \sum_{\jmath=1}^m \frac{g'_\jmath (z_0)}{g_\jmath (z_0)}$

I put the summation symbols at the end because I'm not really sure how to use it while using the quotient rule :/. please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write $h=f_1\cdot ... \cdot f_n \cdot g_1^{-1} \cdot ... \cdot g_m^{-1}$ then 
$$\ln(h)=\sum_{l=1}^n \ln f_l - \sum_{j=1}^m \ln g_j.$$
Then since generally $[\ln u]'=u'/u$ on differentiating the sides you get the equation you want.

To do this problem using the usual product and quotient rules would be notationally involved. For example $[u v w x^{-1} y^{-1}]'$ would already have five terms in it, where in each term one of $u,v,w,x^{-1},y^{-1}$ are differentiated (the others unchanged), not forgetting the chain rule for $x^{-1},y^{-1}$. Then all would have to be collected and the above $h'/h$ factored out, to see the result matches the nice formula obtained using logarithmic differentiation.
(edited but needed 5 more characters so added this in description. sorry! :x)

Comment: wow... i didn't even think of that! you're a genius haha math is so awesome.

Comment: As added above, I think this problem would get messy without logarithmic differentiation!

Comment: sometimes I feel people like you should receive some type of donation. Sharing and learning knowledge is awesome. That's why I love this website. Thanks again! Still really excited and stoked about how it all worked out!